# Express.js - How can I pass a url param from the main router to another router module?

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

In my small chat application, when I make a HTTP call to an endpoint ending in "users" I want my room router to take over. This be with a preceding room name, or with nothing at all.

routes.js:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var roomRoute = require('./routes/room');
    app.use('/:roomname/users', roomRoute);
    app.use('/users', roomRoute);
};
```

Now when my room router takes over, I want to be able to access the room name if it exists in the url. Something like:

./routes/room.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/info', function(req, res) {
    console.log('the roomname is ' + req.roomname);
    res.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Is there any way to easily pass this room name along? I could probably extract it from the baseUrl but I think there is probably a better way...

Comment: `req.params.roomname` doesn't work?

Comment: No -  params is empty after the request is passed on to the room router

Comment: you can even set it in `res.locals`

Answer (score 4):

The router needs to set the `mergeParams` option to true.
http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router

```
let router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

The very next thing I read after I posted had the answer...

In routes.js:

```
var roomRoute = require('./routes/room');
app.use('/:roomname/users', function (req, res, next) {
    req.roomname = req.params.roomname;
    next();
}, roomRoute);
app.use('/users', roomRoute);
```

Comment: Is this the only possibility? Because it is not really a nice way to handle this.